# Create a call graph for a specific function using Doxygen

Tags: graph, doxygen

When I have EXTRACT_ALL, EXTRACT_PRIVATE AND EXTRACT_STATIC all set to YES, then I can create call graphs for almost all entities in my project. But how do I create a call graph for a specific function?

If it is possible, then if I enable INTERACTIVE_SVG, is it possible to access the functions in my call graph or do I have to create a call graph for each called function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit depending on your version of doxygen.
But besides the configuration settings (always needed `HAVE_DOT=YES`):

- `CALL_GRAPH`
- `CALLER_GRAPH`

there are the commands (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html):

- `\callgraph`
- `\callergraph`
- `\hidecallgraph`
- `hidecallergraph`

with these commands it should be possible to create the required graphs.

Upon request:

The doxygen configuration file

```
HAVE_DOT=YES
```

The source code file

```
/// \file

/// \brief the first function
/// \details the details of the first function
/// \callgraph
void fie1(void)
{
  fie2();
};

/// \brief the second function
/// \details the details of the second function
void fie2(void);
```

Comment: I have added \callgraph to a comment above a function and disabled extracting all the other functions, but for some reason it is being ignored (no graph is generated for that function)! Could you edit your answer to show an example, please?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which settings did you do in the doxygen configuration file? How does your example look like?

Comment: I am using Doxygen 1.9.0. I can now see the documentation of the required function that I want, but for some reason I can't find the callgraph itself not really sure why. I have disabled EXTRACT_ALL to see if I can get only the needed graph. I am working on a large project so this is why I was trying to focus on only specific functions.

Comment: OK you have a self compiled version (which sha? `doxygen -v`). What happens when you run my example?

Comment: b6a1dcf9f604707015275b86bcfe0e008cbde248. When I run your example, I get the documentation of the function in question but not the graph eventhough I think I have the parameters required enabled.

Comment: Version is very nicely quite up to date. Can you run my example but with some changes i.e. add `QUIET=YES` to the Doxyfile, remove the html and latex directories and run `doxygen -d extcmd Doxyfile`. Please report back the output that you see on your terminal window.

Comment: Executing external command 'dot "/outputdirectory/html/file_name.dot" -Tpdf -o "/outputdirectory/html/file_name.map/pdf" 

I could only get the file's graph, but not the function. But I can find the documented function according to your example. I had to disable EXTRACT_ALL, otherwise it'd extract all, but I am not sure what exactly I am missing. Could it be that I have to include the all of the dependencies to get the graph for the function? How do I do that tho?

Comment: "I had to disable EXTRACT_ALL" this is strange as in my example only the `HAVE_DOT` is mentioned (and `QUIET=NO`) and all the other settings are at their default. So please create the Doxyfile so that only the lines with `QUIET` and `HAVE_DOT` are present.

Comment: I could only get the graph of the .c file. Not the function, which I am still not really sure why it is happening. In your example, do we consider the function and its dependencies or just the function itself?

Comment: yes sir. The function appears but the graph does not. I documented it exactly like the example.

Comment: Without a small example it is hard to tell what went wrong in your case, so please construct a small example that shows the problem including the the doxygen settings different from the standard settings (use `doxygen -x Doxyfile` to get a minimal set of differences).

Comment: Sorry, I have not been able to construct a simple example yet. As soon as I can then I will update you. At the moment, I am content with the fact that I can create all graphs because in many cases this is the easiest way to access all graphs without any further thinking.

Comment: What is `fie` in the example, please? It looks like a typo for "file", but then the functions are called "file1", which is a strange choice for an random example function name, where the first line is the Doxygen command `\file`. I am new to Doxygen - does `fie` have some special meaning (`function in example`??) here?

Comment: @Matthew the `\file` is there as a placeholder for the file comment block. the word `fie` has no special meaning and is just the name of the function (I don't remember where it originates from maybe from the Dutch "functie" i.e. "function" as an abbreviation) just like "foo", "bar" etc. would be,